# how to ignore cvs folder in Ant script

Tags: ant, cvs, ignore

After building an application by using ant, i am copied the component to a temp folder. But, the cvs folder is also copied and it increases the no of folder and file almost double by number. Is there any solution to ignore cvs folder in ant build file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "exclude" tag in your fileset to specificly remove all the CVS directories.